# Simple script to authenticate with linkedin via browser?

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I want to create my own PHP web app where people can signin with their linkedin account.  I can't seem to find on the internet working example code for me to start from.  I tried the [quick start guide](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide) only to realize the PHP script was meant to be used from terminal, NOT a browser! And additionally, the authentication fails...I get a response array of 3 keys with empty or zero values.

All the sample code I tried from people's blog failed for some reason or another.

Does someone have a simple and functional script for linkedin authentication for web apps I can learn from?

Comment: The PHP script is meant to be executed by a web server. Not the browser, not the terminal.

Comment: @Mr.Omsn , John is right; I remember answering one of his questions yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the right tutorial:

This is overview of the relevant API
https://developer.linkedin.com/javascript

This is Hello FirstName LastName example
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api

Here's an example code that works right out of the box:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
          api_key:myapikey 
  </script>



  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="in/Login">
          Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```